# Fibonacci numbers. how to prove?

Tags: induction, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

We are give Fibonacci numbers.{fi
| i ∈ N}, where f0 = 0, f1 = 1, fn+2 = fn +fn+1, n∈ N. How to proof with mathematical induction that if n divides by m, then fn divides by fm?
 I am having trouble with thinking, what should be the transition.

Comment: Hi & welcome to MSE.  Please show us what you've tried so far & are having difficulty with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prove by induction on $m$ that

$F_{m+n}=F_{m+1}F_n+F_mF_{n+1}-F_m F_n$

Then put $m=kn$ and find that if $F_n|F_{kn}$ then $F_n|F_{(k+1)n}$.

Comment: +1 then -1.  The battle is on!